# Python: Remove all lines of csv files that do not match within a range

Tags: python, csv, match

I have been given two sets of data in the form of `csv` files which have `23` columns and thousands of lines of data.

The data in column `14` corresponds to the positions of stars in an image of a galaxy.

The issue is that one set of data contains values for positions that do not exist in the second set of data.  They need to both contain the same positions, but the positions are off by a value of `0.0002` each data set.

`F435.csv` has values which are `0.0002` greater than the values in `F550.csv`.  I am trying to find the matches between the two files, but within a certain range because all values are off by a certain amount.

Then, I need to delete all lines of data that correspond to values that do not match.

Below is a sample of the data from each of the two files:

**F435W.csv:**

```
NUMBER,FLUX_APER,FLUXERR_APER,MAG_APER,MAGERR_APER,FLUX_BEST,FLUXERR_BEST,MAG_BEST,MAGERR_BEST,BACKGROUND,X_IMAGE,Y_IMAGE,ALPHA_J2000,DELTA_J2000,X2_IMAGE,Y2_IMAGE,XY_IMAGE,A_IMAGE,B_IMAGE,THETA_IMAGE,ERRA_IMAGE,ERRB_IMAGE,ERRTHETA_IMAGE
1,2017.013,0.01242859,-8.2618,0,51434.12,0.3269918,-11.7781,0,0.01957931,1387.9406,541.916,49.9898514,41.5266996,8.81E+01,1.63E+03,1.44E+02,40.535,8.65,84.72,0.00061,0.00035,62.14
2,84.73392,0.01245409,-4.8201,0.0002,112.9723,0.04012135,-5.1324,0.0004,-0.002142646,150.306,146.7986,49.9942613,41.5444109,4.92E+00,5.60E+00,-2.02E-01,2.379,2.206,-74.69,0.00339,0.0029,88.88
3,215.1939,0.01242859,-5.8321,0.0001,262.2751,0.03840466,-6.0469,0.0002,-0.002961465,3248.686,52.8478,50.003155,41.5019044,4.77E+00,5.05E+00,-1.63E-01,2.263,2.166,-65.29,0.002,0.0019,-66.78
4,0.3796681,0.01240305,1.0515,0.0355,0.5823653,0.05487975,0.587,0.1023,-0.00425157,3760.344,11.113,50.0051049,41.4949256,1.93E+00,1.02E+00,-7.42E-02,1.393,1.007,-4.61,0.05461,0.03818,-6.68
5,0.9584663,0.01249223,0.0461,0.0142,1.043696,0.0175857,-0.0464,0.0183,-0.004156116,4013.2063,9.1225,50.0057256,41.4914444,1.12E+00,9.75E-01,1.09E-01,1.085,0.957,28.34,0.01934,0.01745,44.01
```

**F550M.csv:**

```
NUMBER,FLUX_APER,FLUXERR_APER,MAG_APER,MAGERR_APER,FLUX_BEST,FLUXERR_BEST,MAG_BEST,MAGERR_BEST,BACKGROUND,X_IMAGE,Y_IMAGE,ALPHA_J2000,DELTA_J2000,X2_IMAGE,Y2_IMAGE,XY_IMAGE,A_IMAGE,B_IMAGE,THETA_IMAGE,ERRA_IMAGE,ERRB_IMAGE,ERRTHETA_IMAGE,,FALSE
2,1921.566,0.01258874,-8.2091,0,37128.06,0.2618096,-11.4243,0,0.01455503,4617.5225,554.576,49.9887896,41.5264699,6.09E+01,8.09E+02,1.78E+01,28.459,7.779,88.63,0.00054,0.00036,77.04,,
3,1.055918,0.01256313,-0.0591,0.0129,9.834856,0.1109255,-2.4819,0.0122,-0.002955142,3936.4946,85.3255,49.9949149,41.5370016,3.98E+01,1.23E+01,1.54E+01,6.83,2.336,24.13,0.06362,0.01965,23.98,,
4,151.2355,0.01260153,-5.4491,0.0001,184.0693,0.03634057,-5.6625,0.0002,-0.002626019,3409.2642,76.9891,49.9931935,41.5442109,4.02E+00,4.35E+00,-1.47E-03,2.086,2.005,-89.75,0.00227,0.00198,66.61,,
5,0.3506025,0.01258874,1.138,0.039,0.3466277,0.01300407,1.1503,0.0407,-0.002441164,3351.9893,8.9147,49.9942299,41.5451727,4.97E-01,5.07E-01,7.21E-03,0.715,0.702,62.75,0.02,0.01989,82.88
```

Below is the code I have so far, but I'm unsure how to find matches based on that specific column.  I am very new to Python, and this task is probably way beyond my knowledge of Python, but I desperately need to figure it out.  I've been working on this single task for weeks, trying different methods.  Thank you in advance!

```
import csv

with open('F435W.csv') as csvF435:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvF435, delimiter=',')

with open('F550M.csv') as csvF550:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvF550, delimiter=',')

for x in range (0,6348):
    a = csvF435[x]
    for y in range(0,6349):
        b = csvF550[y]

        if b < a + 0.0002 and b > a - 0.0002:
            newlist.append(b)
            break
```

Comment: Can you add samples of the 2 `csv` files you want to manipulate?

Comment: Do you mean an example of what the information in the files looks like? If so, then I added a screenshot of what one of the files looks like.  They are both the same just with slightly different numbers.  I apologize if that is not what you meant.

Comment: Instead of screenshots could you add pieces of the files with matching lines and non matching ones? and expected output. We just need a couple of lines of each files to have a minimal verifiable example

Comment: I don't think that's possible unless I spend hours manually searching through hundreds of lines for matches.  The positions are not in the same order in the files.  Position 2 in the first file may be position 5000 in the second file.  I can do that if necessary, though.

Comment: You can just recreate 2 files with 4,5 lines some matching and some not matching. 
You don't need to have the exact correct data from your original files.

Comment: It will take me more time to create the input files, than what I need to write the code to resolve your problem

cf: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okay I have added some lines that should have matches within 0.0002.  The header for the specific column is 'DELTA_J2000'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189792/discussion-between-allan-and-samantha-martin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following sample:

```
import csv

def isfloat(value):
  try:
    float(value)
    return True
  except ValueError:
    return False

interval = 0.0002

with open('F435W.csv') as csvF435:
 csvF435_in = csv.reader(csvF435, delimiter=',')
 #clean the file content before processing
 with open("merge.csv","w") as merge_out:
   pass
 with open("merge.csv", "a") as merge_out:
  #write the header of the output csv file
  for header in csvF435_in:
    merge_out.write(','.join(header)+'\n')
    break
  for l435 in csvF435_in:
    with open('F550M.csv') as csvF550:
      csvF550_in = csv.reader(csvF550, delimiter=',')
      for l550 in csvF550_in:
        if isfloat(l435[13]) and isfloat(l550[13]) and abs(float(l435[13])-float(l550[13])) < interval:
          merge_out.write(','.join(l435)+'\n')
```

**F435W.csv:**

```
NUMBER,FLUX_APER,FLUXERR_APER,MAG_APER,MAGERR_APER,FLUX_BEST,FLUXERR_BEST,MAG_BEST,MAGERR_BEST,BACKGROUND,X_IMAGE,Y_IMAGE,ALPHA_J2000,DELTA_J2000,X2_IMAGE,Y2_IMAGE,XY_IMAGE,A_IMAGE,B_IMAGE,THETA_IMAGE,ERRA_IMAGE,ERRB_IMAGE,ERRTHETA_IMAGE
1,2017.013,0.01242859,-8.2618,0,51434.12,0.3269918,-11.7781,0,0.01957931,1387.9406,541.916,49.9898514,41.5266996,8.81E+01,1.63E+03,1.44E+02,40.535,8.65,84.72,0.00061,0.00035,62.14
2,84.73392,0.01245409,-4.8201,0.0002,112.9723,0.04012135,-5.1324,0.0004,-0.002142646,150.306,146.7986,49.9942613,41.5444109,4.92E+00,5.60E+00,-2.02E-01,2.379,2.206,-74.69,0.00339,0.0029,88.88
3,215.1939,0.01242859,-5.8321,0.0001,262.2751,0.03840466,-6.0469,0.0002,-0.002961465,3248.686,52.8478,50.003155,41.5019044,4.77E+00,5.05E+00,-1.63E-01,2.263,2.166,-65.29,0.002,0.0019,-66.78
4,0.3796681,0.01240305,1.0515,0.0355,0.5823653,0.05487975,0.587,0.1023,-0.00425157,3760.344,11.113,50.0051049,41.4949256,1.93E+00,1.02E+00,-7.42E-02,1.393,1.007,-4.61,0.05461,0.03818,-6.68
5,0.9584663,0.01249223,0.0461,0.0142,1.043696,0.0175857,-0.0464,0.0183,-0.004156116,4013.2063,9.1225,50.0057256,41.4914444,1.12E+00,9.75E-01,1.09E-01,1.085,0.957,28.34,0.01934,0.01745,44.01
```

**F550M.csv:**

```
NUMBER,FLUX_APER,FLUXERR_APER,MAG_APER,MAGERR_APER,FLUX_BEST,FLUXERR_BEST,MAG_BEST,MAGERR_BEST,BACKGROUND,X_IMAGE,Y_IMAGE,ALPHA_J2000,DELTA_J2000,X2_IMAGE,Y2_IMAGE,XY_IMAGE,A_IMAGE,B_IMAGE,THETA_IMAGE,ERRA_IMAGE,ERRB_IMAGE,ERRTHETA_IMAGE,,FALSE
2,1921.566,0.01258874,-8.2091,0,37128.06,0.2618096,-11.4243,0,0.01455503,4617.5225,554.576,49.9887896,41.5264699,6.09E+01,8.09E+02,1.78E+01,28.459,7.779,88.63,0.00054,0.00036,77.04,,
3,1.055918,0.01256313,-0.0591,0.0129,9.834856,0.1109255,-2.4819,0.0122,-0.002955142,3936.4946,85.3255,49.9949149,41.5370016,3.98E+01,1.23E+01,1.54E+01,6.83,2.336,24.13,0.06362,0.01965,23.98,,
4,151.2355,0.01260153,-5.4491,0.0001,184.0693,0.03634057,-5.6625,0.0002,-0.002626019,3409.2642,76.9891,49.9931935,41.5442109,4.02E+00,4.35E+00,-1.47E-03,2.086,2.005,-89.75,0.00227,0.00198,66.61,,
5,0.3506025,0.01258874,1.138,0.039,0.3466277,0.01300407,1.1503,0.0407,-0.002441164,3351.9893,8.9147,49.9942299,41.5451727,4.97E-01,5.07E-01,7.21E-03,0.715,0.702,62.75,0.02,0.01989,82.88
```

**merge.csv:**

```
NUMBER,FLUX_APER,FLUXERR_APER,MAG_APER,MAGERR_APER,FLUX_BEST,FLUXERR_BEST,MAG_BEST,MAGERR_BEST,BACKGROUND,X_IMAGE,Y_IMAGE,ALPHA_J2000,DELTA_J2000,X2_IMAGE,Y2_IMAGE,XY_IMAGE,A_IMAGE,B_IMAGE,THETA_IMAGE,ERRA_IMAGE,ERRB_IMAGE,ERRTHETA_IMAGE
2,84.73392,0.01245409,-4.8201,0.0002,112.9723,0.04012135,-5.1324,0.0004,-0.002142646,150.306,146.7986,49.9942613,41.5444109,4.92E+00,5.60E+00,-2.02E-01,2.379,2.206,-74.69,0.00339,0.0029,88.88
```